# Prototype and jQuery Issue this._each is not a function

Tags: jquery, magento, prototypejs

I am developing a Magento Website and I am getting an error in IE7+8 + an error in my firebug console:

```
this._each is not a function
[Break On This Error]   
this._each(function(value) {
```

I have noConflict on the jQuery include and this makes no difference, all of my scripts still function as they should but if you look at the code on the website and remove idTabs.js the error disappears... Im really stumbled by this and have spent over an hour now trying to figure it out!

http://www.haircarepro.co.uk

Any help would be deeply appreciated! Thanks for your time.

Comment: If I pasted the code this question would be massive. I have outlined the problem above, if you look at the error console in firebug you can see my error, if you remove idtabs.js the error goes away, but all scripts work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be the `each` function in the `idtabs.js` plugin on line 63. It appears to be looking for a Prototype function called `each` instead of a jQuery one.

try changing :

```
return this.each(function(){ jQuery.idTabs(this,s); }); //Chainable
```

to

```
return jQuery(this).each(function(){ jQuery.idTabs(this,s); }); //Chainable
```

To use the each function of jQuery instead of trying to find it in Prototype.js

Comment: Thanks, however this hasn't worked, still getting the error :(

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use .each() with prototype and jQuery there will be a last element inside the loop that is a function.
So when trying to use other jQuery functions on the elements inside the .each() loop, most of the time, when it gets to the last element it will throw an error or have wrong behaviour.

It may not be the best nor the fastest solution but I  usually fix it by checking if the elements inside the loop are of the type I need or a function with:

```
if (typeof v === 'function') {
    continue;
}
```

This problem is very common when trying to use jQuery libraries with Magento.